# MYSQL Query Mass Pump

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `coupon` SET 
                    `name` = 'FREECOUPON', 
                    `coupon_code` = '" . $this->db->escape($couponCode) . "', 
                    `discount` = '38', 
                    `uses_total` = '22', 
                    `status` = '1'
                ";

                $this->db->query($sql);

                $coupon_id = $this->db->getLastId();

                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO coupon_cat SET coupon_id = '" . (int)$coupon_id . "', category_id = 79  ");
```

The query works, but I want to modify this

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO coupon_cat SET coupon_id = '" . (int)$coupon_id . "', category_id = 79  ");
```

I want to "mass pump" data into `coupon_cat`. I need to pump from category 30-180, but in different lines. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: normally you insert into databases tables rather than any pumping.  You mean you want the same insert but for all categories between 30 and 180? What MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack version 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you clear you want to insert the same coupon_id to 150 category ids. You can insert all the rows in one query using loop to create all the values.

```
$coupon_id = (int)$this->db->getLastId();

$values = [];
for ($category_id = 30; $category_id <= 180; $category_id++) {
    $values[] = '(' . $coupon_id . ',' . $category_id . ')';
}

$this->db->query('INSERT INTO `coupon_cat` (coupon_id, category_id) VALUES ' . implode(',', $values));
```

Comment: but i want it to insert different row instead of using implode

Comment: This will insert 150 (180-30=150) differents rows in database.

Comment: hi , after trying the code 
: syntax error, unexpected '$coupon_id'

^ this error show up

Comment: Fixed. Missed dot.

Comment: sorry for the late response . tried the code but it did not insert to `coupon_cat`

Comment: thanks ,it work now , could i know why removing the '( )' make it works ? confuse on this.

as there is no error previously,it just unable to insert

Comment: Because I forgot to remove them. Query in the previous form would have double '()': `VALUES ((14,15),(14,16))`.